# Elastic Beanstalk Editing Files Online?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my Django website on AWS elastic beanstalk. I have deployed PHP websites previously on GoDaddy and some other hosting.
As there is method to edit your PHP files over internet as I can login my account on another pc and edit the files. But until now I am unable to find a way to do so in elastic beanstalk to let me or some one else to edit the files online.
Currently all my are on my laptop.
It may be silly question but I just want to know.

Answer (score 0):

> But until now I am unable to find a way to do so in elastic beanstalk to let me or some one else to edit the files online.

There is **no such functionality** in EB. If you want it you have to develop such system yourself.